# Take screenshot of desktop when Windows is locked (Win+L)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, screenshot, winlogon

I want to take a screenshot of desktop while Windows is locked (with Win+L). Standard methods make a black screen, with code of pixel:

```
COLORREF color = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
```

equal -1. Neither a user mode program nor a service could capture a useful image. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to get an image of the desktop that would be displayed if it were unlocked, or a shot of the locked screen itself?

Comment: I'm trying to take screenshot of display if it was unlock,
screenshot of Winlogon doesn't interest me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetPixel` and `BitBlt` won't work when the desktop isn't physically displayed on the monitor.

You may have some luck capturing individual windows with [`PrintWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869.aspx). However, not all applications respond to `PrintWindow` calls the same way, so you may see glitches and/or blackness. You'll also need to capture each window individually.

Comment: I correctly understand you: you suggest to organize a cycle and make a screenshot of everyone window?
If I will use HWND parameter equal 0, it will copy to DC all desktop?
In spite of all, thank you.

Comment: It'll ask the desktop to paint itself into the `HDC` of your choice, which I think gets you a copy of the user's wallpaper, and possibly their icons.

Comment: Anticreativshik, did you get any results?

Comment: Cees, yes, a had result, but result was negative. I couldn't get any image in this way, and we closed ticket in bugtracker with mark "as designed"