# Capturing screenshot while workstation is locked

Tags: screenshot, autoit, capture

I would like to capture a screenshot of the monitor or a window, preferably using AutoIt (I am open to using any convenient method). The method needs to be able to function while the workstation is locked, due to the program being run overnight.

I cannot simply put code to unlock the workstation, as it poses a security risk. Current behavior: `_ScreenCapture_SaveImage()` saves a blank screen with only the mouse showing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474805/take-screenshot-of-desktop-when-windows-is-locked-winl

Answer (score 0):

Try using [captdll.dll](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/28217-window-capture-script/?hl=captdll) to capture fullscreen or a program window.

```
$LogFilePath = "C:\Temp"
$TimeStamp = @YEAR & @MON & @MDAY & @HOUR & @MIN & @SEC

; Capture full screen
; Fist parameter - filename, last - jpeg quality.
$erg = DllCall("captdll.dll", "int:cdecl", "CaptureScreen", "str", $LogFilePath & "\Ce2eC_" & $TimeStamp & ".JPG", "int", 75)
```