# Powershell - How to get window screenshot while screen is locked?

Tags: windows, powershell, screenshot

Is there any way to get image of a window while screen is locked?

I'm using Get-Screenshot from RoughDraft to capture window screenshot, but apparently it doesn't work while screen is locked.

In our environment we are using Powershell, so my script looks like this:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Win32Api
{
  public static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute( "User32.dll", EntryPoint =  "GetWindowThreadProcessId" )]
  public static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId ( [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] System.IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId );

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr sClassName, String sAppName);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern uint GetLastError();
}
"@
....cut....

try {
    while ($ProcessActive.Id -ne $null) {
    $find_window = [Win32Api]::FindWindow([IntPtr]::Zero, $wname )
    $ProcessActive = Get-Process -Id $app.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $get_pid = [Win32Api]::GetWindowThreadProcessId( $find_window, [ref] $dbPID );

    if ($find_window -ne 0 -And $dbPID -eq $app.Id) {
        Write-Host "[ERROR]  Warning window found:" $find_window -NoNewline
        Write-Host ", and has parent PID:" $dbPID

    if (Test-Path warning-$dbPID-scr0.JPEG) {
       Write-Host "[STATUS] Old screenshot file exist, cleaning..."
       Remove-Item warning-$dbPID-scr0.JPEG
    }
        Get-ScreenShot -OfWindow -Path warning-$dbPID-scr

        if (Test-Path warning-$dbPID-scr0.JPEG) {
           Write-Host Saved screenshot as warning-$dbPID-scr0.JPEG
        }
    else {
      Write-Host "[ERROR]  Error while saving screenshot!"
    }

        $zero = [IntPtr]::Zero
        $send_close = [Win32Api]::SendMessage( $find_window, [Win32Api]::WM_CLOSE, $zero, $zero )

        Write-Host "[ERROR]  Exit with code 1 (this is not good)"
        exit 1
    }
catch {
   $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
   Write-Host "We'v got this: $ErrorMessage"
}
```

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3474843/67392) I suspect the answer may be: in general you cannot. When the WindownStation is in its locked desktop (the underlying mechanism used for locking) then you cannot, even from within that WindowStation, just read the content of a different desktop.

Comment: Yeah... it seems. But maybe there is a method to copy window text to clipboard or something? Or it is impossible with locked screen?

Comment: That is a very different question. But would require applications to support such a message (just because a Window displays text does not mean Windows knows there is text there: an application could write text to a bitmap and then write the bitmap to the screen);.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a screenshot of a window, applications must call GetDC/GetDCEx to get the device context that represents the screen area of the window.

This always returns a DC that represents the windows position on the display, and is clipped to the windows visible area on the display.

This means that, when you paint to a windows DC, you are painting directly onto the display device, albeit clipped such that you cannot paint outside the bounds of the windows visible area.

It also means that, if you use this DC as a source DC to capture a screenshot of a window, there are literally no pixels for parts of the window that are not visible, on the display device, "right now".

If (and this is a very big IF) the window in question actually supports the WM_PRINT message, you can use the `PrintWindow` API to encourage the window to paint itself onto a DC you provide. This should cause it to paint itself, from scratch, and you might get a good copy of the windows contents.

Comment: Well, it can't be repainted, because it is an exception in some **old legacy** software.